# Scala hide the curiously recursive template pattern

Tags: scala, scala-macros

so - I'm in scala using an interface from java that uses the curiously recurring template pattern - its essentially a clone function:

```
    interface Blah<T>
    { 
        T clone();
    }
```

which means if you have a long nasty class, you have to do:

```
    class LongNastyClass extends Blah[LongNastyClass]
    {...}
```

but of course scala is fairly magical - and has macros and stuff - so I'm wondering if its possible (I couldn't figure out a way) - to hide this mess behind a trait

eg - something like:

```
    trait BlahBetter extends Blah[this.type] {
    }
```

so that anybody who's using it doesn't have to know they are meant to refer to themselves - eg:

```
    class LongNastyClass extends BlahBetter {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would keep `class LongNastyClass extends Blah[LongNastyClass]` (F-bounded polymorphism).

But you can introduce macro annotation

```
import scala.annotation.{StaticAnnotation, compileTimeOnly}
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox

@compileTimeOnly("enable macro paradise")
class blahBetter extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro BlahBetterMacro.impl
}

object BlahBetterMacro {
  def impl(c: whitebox.Context)(annottees: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    annottees match {
      case q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }" :: tail =>
        val tparams1 = tparams.map {
          case q"$_ type $tpname[..$_] = $_" => tpname
        }
        val parents1 = parents :+ tq"Blah[$tpname[..$tparams1]]"
        q"""
          $mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents1 { $self => ..$stats }
          ..$tail
        """
    }
  }
}

@blahBetter
class LongNastyClass

//Warning:scalac: {
//  class LongNastyClass extends scala.AnyRef with Blah[LongNastyClass] {
//    def <init>() = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    }
//  };
//  ()
//}
```

`this.type` is not `LongNastyClass`.